# How to count json items by value in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, count

I got this result from exam and exam_result table :

```
 +--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | exam_id| course_id      |                                        result                                       |
 +--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 18     |       27       | {"38": 2, "39": 2, "41": 0, "42": 1, "43": 0, "44": 1, "45": 0, "49": 0, "73": 1}   |
 | 18     |       27       | {"61": 2, "62": 2, "63": 1, "64": 0, "67": 2, "68": 2, "69": 2, "70": 2}            |
 | 18     |       27       | {"61": 1, "62": 1, "63": 1, "64": 1, "67": 2, "68": 2, "69": 1, "70": 2}            |
 | 18     |       25       | {"61": 2, "62": 2, "63": 1, "64": 1, "67": 2, "68": 1, "69": 2, "70": 1}            |
 | 18     |       25       | {"61": 1, "62": 1, "63": 1, "64": 1, "67": 1, "68": 1, "69": 1, "70": 1}            |
 | 19     |       20       | {"61": 1, "62": 1, "63": 1, "64": 1, "67": 1, "68": 1, "69": 1, "70": 1}            |
 | 20     |       20       | {"81": 0, "82": 1, "83": 0, "84": 0, "85": 0}                                       |
 +--------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

by this query:

```
SELECT ex.`exam_id`,ex.`course_id`,exr.result FROM `exam` as ex 
LEFT join exam_result as exr
   on (exr.exam_id = ex.exam_id)
WHERE ex.classroom_id = 39
```

in result field (JSON) : The **key** indicates the ID of the question and the **value** indicates whether the answer is correct or incorrect `(1=correct , 0=incorrect , 2=timeout)`

i want to count correct , incorrect and timeout values group by cource_id

so how to do it in query?

Comment: There is no good way using MySQL to do what you ask, with the data in this format. You can't even use JSON_TABLE(), because your JSON data is not in an array format.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you decide to store this data in JSON instead of in a normal way with one result per row? It would be much easier to do `SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM exam_result_item WHERE classroom_id = 39 GROUP BY value` of you had one key/value per row.

Comment: Please provide sample data from both tables, as tabular text or `create table` and  `insert` statements. If is unclear how you get different `result` for the same `exam_id`, while you are joining on this column only.

Comment: normalize the result by splitting the result column into rows and then do the calculation

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev